# ¿Cómo mantener formato de word al crear un PDF con PHP 7?

Tags: php7

Estoy realizando un sistema que genera reporte de aprendices. Estos reportes, están en formato .docx. Me solicitaron que, para que no sea tan difícil generar los reportes (a mano) de cada aprendiz, generara un sistema que lo hiciera automáticamente.

Utilizando la librería dompdf, logré hacer esto:

```
<?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

ob_start();

include '../nucleo/conexion.php';

$ficha=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios, aprendices_formacion WHERE aprendices_formacion.documento_usuario=usuarios.documento_usuario AND aprendices_formacion.id_ficha=1850670 LIMIT 1");

while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($ficha)) {

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
    $dompdf->render();

    $shtml = file_get_contents('../archivos/excel/formato de evaluación NUEVO.htm');

    $cuerpo = $shtml;

    $cuerpo=str_replace("Programa_formacion", "AGROINDUSTRIA ALIMENTARIA", $cuerpo);

    $cuerpo=str_replace("Numero_ficha", "1850670", $cuerpo);

    $cuerpo=str_replace("Nombre_aprendiz", $f['nombre_usuario'] . " " . $f['apellido_usuario'], $cuerpo);

    $cuerpo=str_replace("Numero_documento", $f['documento_usuario'], $cuerpo);

    $cuerpo=str_replace("Numero_telefono", $f['celular_usuario'], $cuerpo);

    $cuerpo=str_replace("Correo_persona", $f['correo_usuario'], $cuerpo);

    $codigo = utf8_encode($cuerpo);

    $dom = new DOMPDF();
    $dom->load_html($codigo);
    ini_set("memory_limit", "1020M");
    $dom->render();

    $hoy = date("d-m-Y");

    $dom->stream("Reporte " . $f['nombre_usuario'] . " " . $f['apellido_usuario'] . " - " . $hoy . ".pdf");

}

?>
```

Este código me descarga el PDF con la información reemplazada (lo que necesito que se muestre de cada aprendiz). El problema, es que esta es la plantilla original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HE intentado de todo. La verdad no sé cómo poder mantener el formato. me han dicho que con .rtf, pero no me permite hacer mucho.

Comment: No has intentado hacer la maquetacion de donde se va a recibir la informacion con javascript? O es un archivo estatico?

Comment: Es una plantilla word prediseñada y con un formato estricto. No sé cómo lo podría replicar tal cual.